# How to reuse UITableView from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

in my apps i want to to show a UITableView that exactly same with another UITableView from another class.
Let say in my HomeClass.h i already have UITableView property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *fromTable;
```

and already success implement this fromTable.

However, i also want to use this fromTable again from other class, lets say DetailClass.
So when for example, i push a button in DetailClass, the button will show fromTable, also with all the delegates function like didSelect, etc.

Can i do that instead create other UITableView again in my DetailClass?

Thanks...

Comment: You don't need to reuse the tableview.  You need to reuse its delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the UITableView's Delegate and DataSource methods into an object that you use in both Classes (presumably UIViewController subclasses).

Comment: I second this. If you want to reuse the logic, this the way to go.

If you designed custom cells via Interface Builder, you will need to recreate them for each view or change it so your code creates the elements in the UITableViewCell.